# Pull spreadsheet data from Google Sheets into React web app

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets

Is there any possibility that I can pull all this spreadsheet data from Google into my web app using React?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS is a front-end library for JavaScript. You could integrate the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) into that same JavaScript project. Please check the [API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) to see an example credentials flow. Once that example is integrated in the project, you could develop your own functions to work with Sheets. A way to pull data from a sheet is to use the method [`spreadsheets.values.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get). To get all the data, you only have to fill the `range` parameter with your sheet name.

Comment: by the way, my client have a default spreedsheet file and by reading sheets api docs, it is stated that i need to redesign all of my client spreedsheet table like a database value style. Does there any ways to pull all his spreedsheet data?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by «*i need to redesign all of my client spreedsheet table like a database value style*». If you want to pull all your client's spreadsheet data, you only have to follow the approach described in my answer. Fill the method request with the spreadsheet ID and the desired sheet. The only prerequisite is that your client has shared the Sheet with you.

Comment: in the documentation of Sheets API and as well in some tutorials they design their spreedsheet like a database. But my problem is my client spreedsheet if you see above the image the spreedsheet has been messy formatted.

Comment: If you want to pull all the data from a Sheet, there is no need to format it. You only have to use the method `spreadsheets.values.get` with the relevant parameters. Additionally, I strongly advise against using Sheets as a database. If you really need a database in the future, you could use some solutions like [Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/), but certainly not Sheets.